# touch -r with reference to another server

Tags: linux, bash, remote-access

I used `scp` to copy file between servers without using 'preserve times' option and now want to restore original times of copy using source file times. Of course I can display these times, write it down and modify destination file. But I'm wondering if there is a posibility of using `touch -r` with reference file on remote server. Or if there is any other command/combination of commands which can grant me such goal.

Comment: Removing and refetching with `-p` seems the simplest.

Comment: Yes, you are right in most cases. But not with couple above 100GB files and 10Mbit connection. And this is a scenerio I'm dealing with :-)

Comment: Not in a place where I can experiment, but would `rsync -a` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `touch` an intermediate file and use it to carry the information:

```
ssh user@hostname "touch file -r remote-file"
```

Then `scp -p` the new file back:

```
scp -p user@hostname:file local_destination
```

Then `touch -r` the file you copied in the first place.

Comment: It's more trick then chain of commands I expected. But very creative and of course it solves the problem. So thx.